# MongoDB extract a subItem as Item for all documents

Tags: mongodb, nested

I have a huge set of documents with not needed nested level in one of the fields:

```
{
   _id : ...,
   level_0_key: { 
       level_1_key: {
           param1 : "val1",
           param2 : "val2",
           param3 : "val3"
       }
   }
}
```

The target is to end up with the following structure:

```
{
   _id : ...,
   level_1_key: {
       param1 : "val1",
       param2 : "val2",
       param3 : "val3"
   }
```

}

To do a save change I want to have both level_0_key and level_1_key living together for a while as a main fields in the table.

So, the question is:

How can I copy the the level_1_key of all the documents where it exists and copy it in the same document.

I've tried something like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {"level_0_key": {$exists: true}},
    {$set: {"level_1_key": "level_0_key.level_1_key"}} 
)
```

But it would just insert the string `"level_0_key.level_1_key"` in the selected documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cursor from the query and bulk updates to update the matching documents.

`$set` to create new value and `$unset` to remove old value.

Here is the shell sample.

```
var bulk = db.colname.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
var batch = 50; // Change batch size as you need

db.colname.find(
     {"level_0_key": {$exists: true}},
     {"level_0_key":1}
).forEach(function(doc){ 
    bulk.find( {"_id" : doc._id}).updateOne(
    { "$set": {"level_1_key" : doc.level_0_key.level_1_key}, "$unset":{"level_0_key":""}} 
   ); 
    count++;  
    if (count == batch) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.colname.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        count = 0;
    } 
});

if (count > 0) { 
   bulk.execute(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to other fields when updating a field, so you can't do this by this way.
A workaround for this is to use aggregation, and output in another/current collection.
I disapprove $replaceRoot stage, in case of having some other fields at root level. I'll use combination of $addFields and $project instead, to keep all other fields unchanged :

```
db['01'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
               "level_1_key":"$level_0_key.level_1_key" ,
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "level_0_key":0
            }
        },
        {
            $out: "target_coll"
        },
    ]
);
```

TAKE CARE :

- $out stage will overwrite whole target collection, so in any document is filtered in your aggregation pipeline, it will  definitively disappear from your collection in case of outputing in the current one.